Getting this error in the below code >> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError:
Getting this error in the below code
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/kvkprose/public_html/index.php:48) in /home/kvkprose/public_html/header.php on line 15
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/kvkprose/public_html/index.php:48) in /home/kvkprose/public_html/header.php on line 16
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/kvkprose/public_html/index.php:48) in /home/kvkprose/public_html/header.php on line 17
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/kvkprose/public_html/index.php:48) in /home/kvkprose/public_html/header.php on line 18
$connection = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","*******","******","*********");

if ($connection->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}

function exe_query($conn, $query) 
{ 
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 

  if (!$result) 
  { 
    die("Query failed: " . mysqli_error($conn)); 
  }

  $rows = [];
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  { 
    $rows[] = $row; 
  }

  return $rows; 
}


$company_data=exe_query($connection, "select * from tbl_admin");
 $contact_data=exe_query($connection,"select * from tbl_contact");
 $about_data=exe_query($connection,"select * from tbl_about where id=3");
 $social_data=exe_query($connection,"select * from tbl_social where id=1");
        $full_name  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        $name_array = explode('/',$full_name);
        $count      = count($name_array);
        $page_name  = $name_array[$count-1];


        header("Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=63072000");
        header("X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block");
        header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
        header("Expect-CT: enforce; max-age=30; report-uri='**********");

        $mypage=explode(".",$page_name);


exe_query takes two arguments. You pass only one.

Still getting header error

ArgumentCountError still exists?

yes and not getting data in  $company_data

[edit] your questioin and add exact text of ArgumentCountError. Header already sent is a consequence of outputting error text.

Please take a look at Laravel https://laravel.com/ it will change your life.

Why do you indicate one error in the title but another in the question?  Which one are you actually trying to correct?  Please update the question to clarify.
